# Calculating semi-minor axis of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm coding a solar system animation and so far it's done, but the the orbits of the planets are circular. To make the simulation more realistic, I want to use elliptic orbits. So I visited [Mercury (planet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28planet%29) and [Solar System Exploration: Planets: Mercury: Facts & Figures](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/profile.cfm?Object=Mercury&Display=Facts&System=Metric) pages, but the semi-minor axis of the Mercury (or any other planet) isn't given.

Then I looked for a way to calculate it and found a formula

$$\epsilon=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a}}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}$$

in [Ellipse - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity) page, but my math knowledge falls short in applying it to my situation.

```
Mercury
Semi-major axis     57,909,050 km
Eccentricity        0.205630
Aphelion            69,816,900 km
Perihelion          46,001,200 km
```

Is there a way to calculate the semi-minor axis of Mercury's orbit with the given values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you have got can be rearranged to yield the semi-minor axis,

$b = a \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$, where **a** is the semi-major axis. Substituting each value in the formula gives
$b = (57,909,050) \sqrt{1-0.205630^2}$
$b = 56,671,523 \space km$